# Hover event in graph Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

Goodnight
Possible to implement something like that? in chartjs http://grab.by/C1T6

```
canvas.mouseover = function(e){
    var activePoints = MyCharts.getBarsAtEvent(e);
    console.log(activePoints);
};
```

so it is impossible to catch event(

Answer (score 0):

The chart is wrapped in a div, why dont you just put a move over on that element

```
$(function() {
    $("#element").mouseover(function(e) { /* implementation */ });
});
```

Comment: Just saying, probably because you're using jQuery. I'm trying to do this as well, and do not want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

So a little trick I found is you can use the customTooltip option to call your own function. It takes one object as a parameter, and is either false, or the segment that is being hovered over.